# Do we need a [chess] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do you think [chess](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) tag is helpful?

I introduced it: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess

[World Engineer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/28988/world-engineer) removed it from: 
[Which paradigm to use for writing chess engine?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34952/which-paradigm-to-use-for-writing-chess-engine) as extraneous.

My position is that chess programming is a distinct and well researched field of its own, and since people seem to take interest in the theory behind it, the tag would play a helpful role.

It's also worth noting that the quality of chess-related questions and answers is typically good (in compare to average).

I'm asking about your opinion on the matter, both in the narrow and broad aspect:

- was the tag redundant for this particular question - [Which paradigm to use for writing chess engine?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34952/which-paradigm-to-use-for-writing-chess-engine)
- is it unnecessary in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmers's [chess](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) currently comes up with 5 questions.

- 1 is closed
- All are positively voted
- All are relatively low views (< 500)

Searching programmers for [chess questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=chess+is%3Aquestion) comes back with 36 results.

- (Somewhat surprisingly) All are either neutral or positively voted
- Very few are closed
- A significant number of them are directly related to chess, and not just mentioning the word chess.

For that particular question, I think tagging it with [chess](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) was the right thing to do.  And the search results indicate there are several other questions that could / should have their tags updated.

More broadly, I think [chess](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) is a useful tag for the site and we ought to keep it.  There's a fair amount of material that could get aggregated into that tag.

So I would propose we have a reverse tag-cleanup where we go through the above search and make sure the questions are tagged appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

I removed it as being [overly specific](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) and unlikely to come up in searches of the site. I try not to flood the front page with edits which is why I did not remove it entirely.

Chess analysis as a programming thing is more algorithm theory than software engineering and thus unlikely to come up much as a tag. It's certainly a valid domain and very interesting as a field of research but we have both Game Dev and CS Stack Exchanges where it would find a wider audience.

Game Dev has 6 questions with the tag, only 4 have a positive scores. CS has questions on Chess algorithms and such but lacks the tag. It's a "[Do Not Use](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chess/info)" tag on Stack Overflow. I'm inclined to agree with their perspective.

Comment: I agree with many of the broader points in your answer, but I don't think that we need to cede chess to other SE sites.  I think Programmers can provide a site-unique point of view focusing on the pragmatic aspects of designing chess algorithms.

Comment: I agree with everything you're saying, though I have to say this feels a little low-risk to be worth bothering with. Perhaps in the future somebody's doing some chess algorithm coding and finds a Q on here, it would be handy for them to click the chess tag and find the few others with that tag, so there's the Pro, and "it's not necessary" is kind of a neutral point, I find no Con to having this tag for us because it won't explode or be abused. I would side with keeping it until there appears reason to clean it out, this can always be done later if some problem arises.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Just playing devils advocate here, but when typing a question about Chess the suggestions were actually pretty close without the existence of a chess tag.  With that being said, I think that it is on topic and a low interest thing so I don't see any cons to keeping the chess tag.  I also don't particularly care to circumvent a fellow mods decision over something like this.  Perhaps if this answer gets negatively scored I will.